# SQL Server 2008 SELECT Concatenation and LEFT of specific character

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following code concatenating a series of text to one field.  Each hit in this query has data following a `^`. I only want to display every LEFT of the `^` and not the `^` itself. Is this possible?

Here is my code...

```
SELECT Cast(Cast(((SELECT *
   FROM   (SELECT(SELECT cddesc + ' ' AS [text()]
   FROM   costdesc
      WHERE  costdesc.cindex = c.cindex
      ORDER  BY cdline
      FOR xml path('')) AS cddesc) cddesc)) AS
   NVARCHAR(max)) AS NTEXT) AS cddesc

FROM Table
WHERE Blah blah
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

-Nick

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you mean each `cddesc` is `'^something'` or `'something^'` ...

Ways to remove first or last characters :

`select substring('abcdef',2,8000)` = `'bcdef'`
`select substring('abcdef',1,len('abcdef')-1)` = `'abcde'`

or if it's in the middle

`select substring('ab^cd',CharIndex('^', 'ab^cd')+1,8000)` = `'cd'`
`select substring('ab^cd',1,CharIndex('^', 'ab^cd')-1)` = `'ab'`

Comment: Example cddesc:  This is a full description concatenated as one string with quite a bit of detail. ^Here is some info after a carrot, I do not want to be shown in the results.

Answer (score 0):

So something like this?

```
DECLARE @TestString VARCHAR(100) = 'This is ^a test';

-- get everything to the left of ^   
SELECT SUBSTRING(@TestString,1,CHARINDEX('^', @TestString)-1);

-- get everything to the right of ^ 
SELECT SUBSTRING(@TestString,CHARINDEX('^', @TestString)+1,LEN(@TestSTring));
```

Resulting in:

`This is`

`a test`

Comment: I get how the SUBSTRING and CHARINDEX works in these excellent examples.  I'm having an issue on where to place it all around my current SELECT CAST(CAST(data)) etc etc query.

Comment: You can put it around a column, a complete select statement, a cast, or anything else that returns a string type value.  Not having your database schema nor an exact understanding of your intent makes it hard to give you an exact answer.